# Cycle notation permutations question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, permutations, symmetric-groups

Consider a square. Split every edge in half. Then lable each half-edge clockwise using the elements of the following $Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]$ which denote the set $Y$. Then the elements of $Y$ are permuted by the elements of the symmetry group (dihedral group) $D_8$.

In cycle notation write the 8 permutations of $Y$.

**Write the effect of 8 elements of D8 to Y in cycle notation.**

Thank you to Bungo for the great guideline:

90 degree clockwise is:

(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
(3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2)
Which returns us with **(1 3 5 7) (2 4 6 8)**

90 degree anticlockwise is:
(1753)(2864)

**Question now solved. Special thanks to Bungo for guiding me on the right path.**

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I meant to attach my working out. One moment.

Comment: @tired  The issue that I have with the posed question is that in previous work like last week I was looking at this question but for a square with the symmetric group Y= [1234] and so naturally the 8 permutations for this are: (1,2,3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,3), (2,4), (1,4,3,2), (1,2)(3,4), (1,4)(2,3), (). It is only that this set contains 8 elements with  the notion of labling each **bold(half-edge )** clockwise is stumbling me. Should there not be a lot more than 8 permutations as in this:

Comment: i think so too: $D_8\sim S_4$ (4 reflections, 4 rotations) is isomorphic to the symmetires of a usual square , so a lot more should going on in your example

Comment: i would guess it is something like $D_8\times Z_2$ because you can additionally exchange any two half edges which induces a total of $2048$ permutations if i am not mistaken

Comment: y, what you said makes sense. ofc I neglected the exchanging of the two half edges. One moment, I will have another go at this.

Comment: i'm not an expert in group theory, but your geometrical construction is also topological equivalent to an regular octagon which has (obviously )symmetry $ D_{16}$, right?

Comment: No it should be D8. As in the elements of group symmetry D8 permute set Y. And I was told that there are explicitly 8 elements.

Comment: Hi I have re-edited the question. I hope it makes more sense?

Comment: Yes thank you I should be a lot more clear. I definetly get the first example rotate 90 deg a.c. since 1 goes to 3, 7 goes back to 1 etc. I get how that is done. Thank you.  What I have trouble with explicitly is figuring out all the mappings. As in say one would be 90 deg ac. another 90 deg c, then 180 deg c/ac would be another. But then I am stuck figuring the other rotaitions. I apologise my for misconceptions I am mostly new to this field.

Comment: @princetongirl818 The eight elements of $D_8$ are the same as usual: the identity, rotation by $+90$, $-90$, and $180$ degrees, and flips across the vertical, horizontal, and the two diagonal axes. The group is still the same 8 dihedral symmetries of the square, even though we have changed the labeling of the sides.

Comment: Thank you again, this clarifies it. I will report back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by drawing a picture:
[image]
We want to know what happens to the segments $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ when $D_8$ acts in the usual way on the square.

Let's consider rotation clockwise by 90 degrees. This will move $1$ to $3$, and $3$ to $5$, and $5$ to $7$, and $7$ to $1$. Similarly, it will move $2\mapsto 4 \mapsto 6 \mapsto 8$. Therefore in cycle notation, this rotation is $(1357)(2468)$.

Next consider rotation by 180 degrees. This will move $1$ to $5$, and $5$ to $1$. Similarly, it will exchange $2$ and $6$, and it will exchange $3$ and $7$, and it will exchange $4$ and $8$. So, in cycle notation, rotation by 180 degrees is $(15)(26)(37)(48)$.

The other six elements of $D_8$ are the identity, rotation counterclockwise by 90 degrees, and flips across the horizontal, vertical, and the two diagonal axes. See if you can do these for yourself, and I encourage you to update your question if you get stuck or want to check your answers.

Comment: An extremely useful guideling, thank you for posting. I believe I posted earlier. I will certainly update my work.Thank you.

Comment: Hi, if we rotate 90 degrees a.c. then is it:  (1753)(2864) I checked with someone else and they said it is the same as doing it 90 deg clockwise.

Comment: @princetongirl818 Yes, $(1753)(2864)$ is correct for rotation anticlockwise by $90$ degrees. Note that this is the inverse of rotation clockwise. This is reflected in the cycle representation: $(1753)$ is the inverse of $(1357)$ and $(2864)$ is the inverse of $(2468)$.

Comment: Next sir, may I ask if for: The identity is it: (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7) (8). Then for the flip across the horizontal: (16) (25) (38) (47). Then for the flip across vertical: (12) (38) (47) (56). I think this is correct. Is there any difference if it (16) OR (61) when both 1 maps to 6 and 6 maps to 1? Thanks :)

Comment: And flipping across the 2 diaganolas gives us: (18) (27) (36) (45) and also (14)(23)(58)(67)

Comment: In general we have that; 1. (1357)(2468)

2. (1753)(2864)

3. (16) (25) (38) (47)

4. (12) (38) (47) (56)

5. (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7) (8)

6. (15) (26) (37) (48)

7. (18) (27) (36) (45)

8. (14) (23) (58) (67) 


Are these correct

Comment: @princetongirl818  Your flip across the horizontal is incorrect. (16)(25) is right, but 3 doesn't go to 8 and 4 doesn't go to 7. Your flip across the vertical is correct. (16) and (61) mean exactly the same thing.  Your diagonal flips are correct. You can write the identity as (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8) if you like, that's the full cycle notation. In the more compact notation we usually exclude the 1-cycles. Since the identity only has 1-cycles, we might simply call it "id" or "1" for shorthand. (Use whatever notation your instructor or textbook prefers.)

Comment: You are amazing, yes I made that mistake rather rashly. Having got the vertical one right I should have got the horizontal one too. tysm :)

Comment: Hi, suppose further that I wanted to say: find the order of each of the elements. Is that simply the number of the elements in a given bracket. So say for the 1st one which was (1357)(2468) would the order be 4? Or do we instead consider the individual elements within a set :?

Comment: @princetongirl818 In general if you have a product of disjoint cycles such as $(ab)(cde)$, the order of that element is the least common multiple of the orders of the individual factors. In this example, $(ab)$ has order 2, and $(cde)$ has order 3, and the least common multiple of these is 6, so $(ab)(cde)$ has order 6. In your example, $(1357)(2468)$, both factors have order 4, so their least common multiple is also 4, hence the order of $(1357)(2468)$ is 4.

Comment: @princetongirl818 You can also find the orders by forgetting about the cycle representation and focusing on the geometry. For example, rotation by 90 degrees obviously has order 4, rotation by 180 degrees has order 2, and every flip has order 2, and the identity has order 1.

Comment: Thank you sir, I see what you mean. Your way makes sense yes. Thanks

Comment: I have one last question on this area please. If I wanted to show that the dihedral group, D8 action on the set Y is proper do you know how I would do that please?

Comment: @princetongirl818 What is the definition of a proper action?

Comment: That is when we have,  G×X->X×X(g,x) -->(g*x,x) where G is the group and X is the space.

Comment: Would I apply that by proposing that D8 is the group action on the set Y which ensures that it is a proper action. Thanks again for the continued assistance